# Is there a simple mistake in this seminal game theory paper?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, game-theory

In Milgrom and Roberts (1990) (http://www.uvm.edu/pdodds/files/papers/others/1990/milgrom1990b.pdf), on page 1266, in the proof of Theorem 5, last line (...but then, by (A2)...).

To put their argument in a broader context, they say: Take a function $f:X\times Z \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and suppose that $f$ is continuous in $z \in Z$ for fixed $x \in X$, and continuous in $x \in X$ for fixed $z \in Z$, so separately, but not jointly, continuous.

Suppose that  $(x_{n},z_{n})_{n \geq 1} \subseteq X \times Z$ is a sequence that converges to some $(x^{\star},z^{\star})$, and that for some $x \in X$,

$$ f(x,z^{\star})>f(x^{\star},z^{\star}). $$

They then make the following argument: Due to the continuity assumptions, there exists some $n$ such that

$$ f(x,z_{n})>f(x_{n+1},z_{n}). $$

Now, for reasons that are clear in the paper, this would be a contradiction. However, disregarding the game theory behind it, I don't see how you make this argument without joint continuity. To see why, let us consider the obvious attempt at applying separate continuity: For $z^{\star}$ fixed, we can use continuity in $x$ to guarantee some $N$ such that for all $k \geq N$,

$$ f(x,z^{\star})>f(x_{k},z^{\star}), $$

this is fine. Now we can apply continuity in the $z$ argument: There exists some $N'$ such that for all $m \geq N'$,

$$ f(x,z_{m})>f(x_{k},z_{m}). $$

However, notice that the $N'$ chosen for the $z$ argument must be done with a fixed $x_{k}$ to begin with. Therefore, if $N'$ is larger than $k$ (if $N'>k$), we cannot guarantee that we can find some $n$ such that

$$ f(x,z_{n})>f(x_{n+1},z_{n}), $$

as required. In fact, it seems to me that if one were able to make such an argument, you would be able to show that separate continuity implies both joint upper and lower semi-continuity, which would imply continuity, which we know is not always true.

Maybe I'm missing something obvious here. If so, any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You say "to put it in a broader context", so did you generalize it? Maybe the generalization does not hold but the original statement does. What where the exact assumptions of the paper?

Comment: They assume "order upper-semicontinuity" in one argument and "order continuity" in the other in order to work on abstract lattices. Let's just assume that the domains of each argument are intervals of the real line, so that order (semi) continuity is simply (semi) continuity, and let's just go ahead and say continuity in both arguments separately and drop the semi-continuity stuff. My assumptions are then subsumed by theirs, but I still don't see how the argument can be made.

Comment: As every function with a discrete domain is continuous , continuity is suplerflous.  The condition on f contradictory.

Comment: Well, they assume domains are complete lattices. An interval on the real line qualifies as that as well, which is "easy" to work with but isn't discrete,so I've been trying to show it in that context. Still no luck

Comment: Check whether their argument follows from supermodularity.